# Сравнение сегментов массивов длиной в 20 байт

Tags: c#, массивы, .net, инспекция-кода, сравнение

Мне нужно сделать быстрое сравнение сегментов массивов `ArraySegment<byte>`, я написал простой метод сравнения:

```
public bool CompareByHash(HandsShakeMessage otherMessage)
{
    ArraySegment<byte> currentSegment =
        new ArraySegment<byte>
        (
            this,
            _handsShakeMessageBytes[0] + 9,
            20
        );

    ArraySegment<byte> otherSegment =
        new ArraySegment<byte>
        (
            otherMessage,
            otherMessage._handsShakeMessageBytes[0] + 9,
            20
        );

    ulong fl = 0UL, sl = 0UL;
    uint fi = 0U, si = 0U;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (i < 16)
        {
            fl = (currentSegment.Array[currentSegment.Offset + i] & 0xffffffffffffffff) << i;
            sl = (otherSegment.Array[currentSegment.Offset + i] & 0xffffffffffffffff) << i;
            continue;
        }

        fi = (currentSegment.Array[currentSegment.Offset + i] & 0xffffffff) << i;
        si = (otherSegment.Array[currentSegment.Offset + i] & 0xffffffff) << i;

    }

    return fl == sl && fi == si;
}
```

Но мне что-то подсказывает что я не правильно заполняю биты, для получения `ulong`'ов и `uint`'ов.

Все ли тут правильно, и что не правильно?

Comment: Почему просто не сравнить их побайтово?

Comment: Мои пять копеек 1) ArraySegment лучше заменить на Span/ReadOnlySpan 2) С SIMD возможно будет быстрей. [Статейка](https://habr.com/ru/post/435840/) где кок раз сравнивают массивы.

Comment: @Vasek, странно конечно, но `memcmp` всех там обыграл :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Ты ничего не экономишь, т. к. всё равно делаешь цикл на 20 итераций.
2. В ulong 8 байт, в uint 4 байта, значит выражение в Return сравнивает не более 12 байт из 20, а значит весь **код работает неверно** независимо от внутренностей (которые тоже неверные).
3. Вроде как к элементам сегмента можно обращаться через квадратные скобки вместо того, чтобы что-то суммировать со сдвигом.
4. Если уж хочется суммировать, то нет никакого смысла вообще использовать ArraySegment - всё решается гораздо проще циклом с другим начальным значением.
5. Объединение по несколько байт работает быстрее только если оно сделано на уровне железа с обращением к нескольким байтам памяти за раз, эмулировать его бесполезно.
6. Обращения к невыровненной памяти могут не работать или работать медленно, так что пытаться вызывать подобные операции явно на адресах может быть опасно.
7. В Си++ есть функция memcmp, которая решает перечисленные пунктом выше проблемы. Можно [пытаться](//stackoverflow.com/q/3000803/4928642) вызвать её на соответсвующей памяти, но я не могу гарантировать, что так получится лучше.
8. Можно пытаться самому сделать аналогичную функцию на указателях со switch по первому байту и соответсвующими манипуляциями по хвосту, но я сильно сомневаюсь, что она оправдает себя.

Одной из наиболее оптимальных (но без особых манипуляций) реализаций является такая:

```
public bool CompareByHash(HandsShakeMessage otherMessage)
{
  for (int l = _handsShakeMessageBytes[0] + 9, r = l + 20, ol = otherMessage._handsShakeMessageBytes[0] + 9; l < r; ++l, ++ol)
    if (_handsShakeMessageBytes[l] != otherMessage._handsShakeMessageBytes[ol])
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

Если требуется обеспечить константность времени работы, то так:

```
public bool CompareByHash(HandsShakeMessage otherMessage)
{
  byte res = 0;

  for (int l = _handsShakeMessageBytes[0] + 9, r = l + 20, ol = otherMessage._handsShakeMessageBytes[0] + 9; l < r; ++l, ++ol)
    res |= _handsShakeMessageBytes[l] ^ otherMessage._handsShakeMessageBytes[ol]);

  return res == 0;
}
```

Comment: не понял, чем второй вариант более константный, чем первый?

Comment: @tym32167, первый делает сравнения только до первого несовпадения, а второй - всегда 20. Речь о предотвращении [атаки по времени](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8), а не об ускорении алгоритма. Всё-таки проверки хэндшейков смахивают на криптографию, поэтому решил написать.

Comment: Хотя вообще есть вероятность, что без условного перехода код отработает быстрее, но тут я вообще ничего утверждать не хочу.

Comment: оо, вот про такую атаку я ещё не слышал, спасибо )

Comment: Но ведь второй способ работает не всегда. Возьмём массивы длины 3, например. {1, 2, 0} и {0, 3, 0}.

Comment: @Kamushek, всегда. `(1^0) | (2^3) | (0^0)` получается `1`, что нулю не равно. Там же `|`, а не `^` при объединении.

Comment: А вот `|` я как-то просмотрел)))

Comment: `_handsShakeMessageBytes[l] != otherMessage._handsShakeMessageBytes[l]` `ol` не используется, опечатка?

Comment: @ヒミコ да, исправил.

Answer (score 2):

**Вы неверно сравниваете их**. Хотя бы потому что вы буквально теряете начальные значения, когда работаете с лонгами, т.к. вы постоянно их обновляете, а сравниваете только в конце.

Я бы посоветовал сравнить их побайтово, или если так хотите делать лишние операции, то можно воспользоваться [BitConverter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=netframework-4.8) *(Внутри реализован через `fixed`)*.
Для сравнения 20 байт вы не заметите разницы при использовании любого алгоритма. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что тут есть жажда излишних "оптимизаций".
**Если бы мы могли** безопасно взять адрес массивов в `unsafe`, не закрепляя объекты в памяти *(`fixed`)*, то мы могли бы взять `int*` и спокойно проверять по 4 байта за раз, и в таком случае **возможно** это было бы оправдано, но оверхэд на закрепление в этом случае явно больше.

А если мы будем пытаться переводить **прочитанные** байты в более длинные числовые типы, а потом сравнивать их, то мы очевидно не получим никакого выигрыша в производительности, а только наоборот.

Comment: Кстати да, про необходимость fixed я забыл. А вот кастить в int* что-то со случайным сдвигом - на x86 прокатит, а на всём остальном - нет.

Comment: Поэтому я и выделил слово "возможно" XD